# How to make effect of ZoomIn ZoomOut in apeareance of Screen in Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, zooming

I am able to rotate the screen with the help of scene2D but I also want that when screen is rotating for particular duration my screen appeared with zoomout effect in libgdx. I am doing as follows:

```
private Stage stage;
```

in update method

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();

@Override
public void show() {

    stage = new Stage();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    Image splashImage = new Image(region);

     splashImage.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.moveTo(0,10, 0.5f),
     //move actor to 200,200
     Actions.rotateTo(360, 1f), //rotate actor to 90°
     Actions.fadeOut(0.5f), //fade out actor (change alpha to 0)
     Actions.removeActor()));
             stage.addActor(splashImage);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Actions.scaleBy(amountX, amountY) or Actions.scaleTo(x, y) or Actions.sizeTo(x, y) ..